# Sort an array of NSDictionary based on dates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdate, nsdictionary

I'm looking for a way to sort an `NSMutableArray` of dictionaries based on dates contained in the dictionaries. Each one looks like this:

```
{
  name: tom, 
  surname: smith, 
  date of birth (NSDate): 2013-02-21 15:25:27
}
```

I know of the methods `earlierDate` etc., but since they only compare two dates I'm just a bit stuck on how to iterate through the array so that I come out with a fully ordered array of dictionaries?

Comment: Nope, need to sort by date not by ascending order on the key

Comment: Did you read the answers? Try anything?

Comment: Did you read the spec for NSArray???????  There are several sort routines that can be adapted to do this.

Answer (score 5):

using `sortUsingComparator` this can be solved easily:

```
[yourArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
   return [a[@"dateOfBirth"] compare:b[@"dateOfBirth"]];
}];
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a viable approach for an `NSMutableArray` of dictionaries where the dictionaries have a key of `@"dateOfBirth"`.